# How do run a keyframe animation with CSS3 concurrently with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

How can I make a CSS3 transition run concurrently with a jQuery `fadeIn`?

I am trying to make a modal pop up fade in, and an overlay also fade in over the page at the same time.

At present, the overlay fades in after a delay of 5s (`5000`). However the keyframe animation doesn't start until 5s after that? I want them both to start at the same time.

The transition for the overlay is coded as such:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal-newsletter-wrap").delay(5000).fadeIn(1000);
    window.setTimeout(function(){$(".page-wrap").addClass("blur");}, 5000);
});
```

And the modal pop-up coded as such:

```
.modal-newsletter {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fx 1s linear 5s 1 forwards;
}
```

If they are both set to `5s / 5000` then why does the jQuery play completely first, and then 5s later the keyframe animation kicks in?

Full working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/5ho8j78d/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effects are automatically placed at the end of the effects queue, unless specified otherwise. Switch the order, and the blur will occur first.

In order to make them appear simultaneously, you could do this:

**CSS**

```
.modal-newsletter-wrap {
    opacity:0;
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        $(".page-wrap").addClass("blur");
        $(".modal-newsletter-wrap").animate({
            queue: false,
            opacity: 1  
          },1000);
    }, 5000);

});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/miqi180/uvhu9v2v/2/)